# How do I prevent domains from resolving to a specific address?

Tags: networking, internet, dns, dnsmasq

When I misspell a domain name, the DNS servers of my ISP provider resolve the domain name to an IP address of a web server that tells you *"we're sorry, the address you typed does not exist"* together with some ads.

For example:

```
$ dig abcdefghijklmo.com           # using the DNS from my ISP
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
abcdefghijklmo.com. 0   IN  A   31.199.53.9
...

$ dig abcdefghijklmo.com @8.8.8.8  # using Google's DNS
... no "ANSWER SECTION" ...
```

As you can see, I'm getting that useless A record instead of an empty answer. I want to get rid of that record.

From my computer I can see that the DNS server is `192.168.1.1`, which is the address of my router. I could change from `192.168.1.1` to `8.8.8.8`, but I would lose the ability of resolving names within my LAN, so it is not an option. My router cannot be configured in any way, I cannot change it and I do not want to run a name server on another device. I contacted my ISP and they have explicitly said that they won't help me.

**TL;DR:** I must use `192.168.1.1` as name server, but I want to filter out answers containing `A 31.199.53.9`. How can I do that?

---

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 with NetworkManager and dnsmasq.

Comment: That's what I call DNS spoofing... What unbelievable crappy ISP is this?!

Comment: If you must use the gateway as DNS, can't you set a different DNS there instead of your ISPs?

Comment: @Nephente: unfortunately no. I cannot configure my router in any way.

Comment: @user16538 you might not be able to configure the router, but have you considered configuring your ubuntu machine to use custom dns ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `/etc/hosts` entry on your Ubuntu.

1. Make sure in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on `dns` line the first option is `files`.
2. Add line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
 abcdefghijklmo.com    ip_address
```

Comment: I want an NXDOMAIN error when resolving `abcdefghijklmo.com`. I do not want it to resolve another IP address.

Comment: no you cant.  to get `NXDOMAIN` error the entry must be deleted from DNS. `NXDOMAIN` or other DNS error are feedback from DNS server.